# .net httpclient Charset encoding is different than Fiddler

Tags: c#, json, encoding, httpclient, utf-32

I'm currently working with an api that requires me to send a json in UTF-32 encoding format.

I am using `HttpClient` lib but it does not encode my json the way Fiddler does so the server returns error. I've googled for hours but without success, anyway here's my raw request (Fiddler):

```
POST http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-32
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 92
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"jsonKey":"JsonValue"}
```

The encoded content looks like this:

[image]

and here's my simple C# request:

```
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8080") }))
{
    _ = await client.PostAsync("http://example.com", new StringContent("{\"jsonKey\":\"JsonValue\"}", Encoding.UTF32, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

C#'s content looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Encoding is used with UTF-8.  You have utf-32.  Usually webpages use the Country in the header to determine the encoding since the country determines the language and character set.  Some country that use more than one language will have more than one country setting.

Comment: The error you are getting is due to "Expect : 100 continue".  Http has two versions 1.0 stream mode and 1.1 chunk mode.  Chunk mode expects to you to send a next chunk message when a 100 is returned.  Instead set you client to 1.0 mode using code like this :             HttpWebRequest request =  (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("URL");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: @jdweng both those comments are irrevelant to the question, and arguably wrong.

Comment: Looking at the `Content-Length` header, is the request made by Fiddler encoding the content as ASCII/UTF-8, but then setting a `Content-Type` header indicating that it's UTF-32 (which is a lie)?

Comment: @jdweng: No, the country definitely does not determine the encoding. It's entirely reasonable to encode content using UTF-32, although it's odd to *require* that.

Comment: I've just tried this, and it worked fine for me. I suggest you use the HexView to see the exact *bytes* that are in the request. I agree with yaakov that it looks like when you're making the request with Fiddler directly, it's not actually using UTF-32.

Comment: Is this API public, and if so could you point to any documentation about requiring UTF-32? I wonder whether it's actually just wrong, and it needs UTF-8 (which is much more common)... I would suggest *trying* UTF-8 instead from C#.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Then why are people saying using the Windows Encoding in HTML is no longer used?  What determines the encoding method to use in a browser?  How does a website respond if it accepts more than one language.

Comment: @jdweng: Encoding and language are entirely separate. If a web site wants to respond to language headers in order to serve content in the right language, it can do that even if uses UTF-8 to encode that content regardless of language. As for using Windows encodings in HTML (it's not like there's one "Windows Encoding") - it's a good idea not to use Windows-specific encodings as that reduces portability on non-Windows devices. Again, that's entirely separate from language.

Comment: @JonSkeet unfortunately the api is private and i have tested plz paste the fiddler request i provided in the "Raw" tab under composer tab in fiddler using parsed tab won't give the same results.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : I know the differences between encoding an language.  From what I know using Windows Encoding on Webpages is no longer used.  The Webbrowsers recognize the language in the header to determine the encoding.  I've look at lots of webpages and I never see the encoding method except UTF-8, or UTF-16.  UTF-8 only specified that the characters are 8 bit and not how to map the language specifc characters.The language is the only way browser can determine the correct character mapping.It is obvious from the sniffer results the c# is not sending the 100 continue and only getting one chunk.

Comment: @MeisamHashemi: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm 99.9% sure that .NET is doing the right thing here, and Fiddler isn't *actually* using UTF-32. I suspect the API really wants UTF-8 despite the documentation.

Comment: @jdweng: "The language is the only way browser can determine the correct character mapping." Um, no. That's the whole point of specifying the encoding in a header - what else do you think the `charset` part of the `Content-Type` header is for? I think it's probably best to leave this conversation at this point, as we seem to be poles apart...

Comment: Most webpage these day do no have only utf-8,16,32 and do not have an encoding like Windows-1251.  Instead have En-US

Comment: @jdweng: En-US is simply *not* an encoding. It doesn't say anything about how to convert between binary data and text, which is what encodings are about.  Whereas web pages usually *do* specify an encoding in the content type - for example, this very page specifies a content type of "text/html; charset=utf-8" as I'd expect. After all, a browser absolutely needs to know how to convert between the binary data it receives and text, or it can't display anything. But I don't know why you introduced languages into this question at all - the question is entirely about encodings.

Comment: @jdweng: As for "Most webpage these day do no have only utf-8,16,32 and do not have an encoding like Windows-1251" - I've just tried Stack Overflow, BBC News, CNN, Reddit, Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Twitter. Every single one of them specified a content type header including an encoding. (All except BBC News specified UTF-8; that used ISO-8859-1.) It's possible I misunderstood your comment, but if you were claiming that they don't specify an encoding, instead specifying a language, can you give examples of major sites which *don't* specify the encoding? Either that, or clarify your comment.

Comment: I'm trying to find the comment somebody made last month.  When I suggested to use Windows-1251 I was told it was obsolete.  I suspecting it may of been an html email, but I can't find the link.  Not sure why email would be treated differently.  It would make sense to use either encoding or language (but not both).  Did the webpage you check have a language?  Did the sites support more than one language?

Comment: @jdweng: I certainly wouldn't recommend using Windows-1251 (using a portable encoding is almost always a better idea), but that doesn't make *encodings* obsolete as a concept. And it makes complete sense to specify both the language and the content. They mean entirely different things. If you're creating a machine learning data set on web pages, you need to know which *human* language the text is in, as well as how to decode the bytes to text in the first place. Having just checked a couple, they didn't specify language - but it would make sense to do so.

Comment: I've voted to close this question though, as we definitely need more information in order to be helpful. The C# code is doing exactly as it should: posting using UTF-32. As I've said before, I suspect whatever documentation is claiming that UTF-32 is required is simply wrong, and using UTF-8 is the way forward.

Comment: `HttpClient` does not require UTF-8; `StringContent` will use the encoding you ask it to. What is likely happening here is that Fiddler is not actually sending things out as UTF-32, while HttpClient is. Fiddler is probably sending it as raw ASCII or whatever your current ANSI code page is.

Comment: I've spoken to the server guys and they added utf-8 support to their API. stupid thing they should've done at the first place. i think @CoryNelson was right. fiddler changes the encoding charset in the header but not actually changes the charset. honestly i have no idea what is going on here and how those servers work!